# Spring security access denied handler not working

Tags: spring-security

I have a spring security app, I have following code in security-context.xml

```
      <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" 
      login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
      default-target-url="/home.jsp" 
      authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" /> 
      <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />      
      <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />          
</security:http>
```

And I have denied.jsp page in views section.

I have main controller in which I have requestmapping for /denied.

But when unauthorized user clicks on a link, I get system error page. It does not get redirected to denied.jsp.

Am I missing any configuration here.

Am I missing anything here? Do I need to add any more

Comment: Describe the error page, plus what you see in the debug log. Also note that the access-denied-handler only applies to authenticated users.

Comment: This is what error page displays.

Comment: Info icon  
The website declined to show this webpage
 
  HTTP 403 
 
    
Most likely causes:
•This website requires you to log in.
 
    
What you can try:
 
    

  Go back to the previous page.  
 
    

More information

Comment: User is an authenticated user. Just not allowed to view this page as per his role. Issue is its not getting redirected to the denied.jsp